# Facebook - How to remove loading screen from Instant Games

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-instant-games

I am currently running into some trouble of trying to remove the loading screen from Facebook Instant Games.

I have tried following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/getting-started/quickstart) Quick Start tutorial. Unfortunately, the loading screen still appears.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvwMR.png)

I am using the Unity game engine to create games. Any recommendations on how to remove it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using the Instant Games API. For example:

```
FBInstant.intializeAsync().then(() => {
  // load your game
  return FBInstant.startGameAsync();
}).then(() => {
  // your game logic
});
```

You can't use this API directly from C# as it's a JavaScript API. To use JavaScript from Unity see this tutorial: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the response. I actually found the solution to this a few days back, but did not find the time to post an answer.